# Efficient hash map container in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, hashmap, hashtable, unordered-map

I want to count unique blocks stored in a file using Haskell.
The block is just consecutive bytes with a length of 512 and the target file has a size of at least 1GB.

This is my initial try.

```
import           Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB
import           Data.Foldable
import           Data.HashMap
import           Data.Int
import qualified Data.List            as DL
import           System.Environment

type DummyDedupe = Map LB.ByteString Int64

toBlocks :: Int64 -> LB.ByteString -> [LB.ByteString]
toBlocks n bs | LB.null bs = []
              | otherwise = let (block, rest) = LB.splitAt n bs
                            in block : toBlocks n rest

dedupeBlocks :: [LB.ByteString] -> DummyDedupe -> DummyDedupe
dedupeBlocks = flip $ DL.foldl' (\acc block -> insertWith (+) block 1 $! acc)

dedupeFile :: FilePath -> DummyDedupe -> IO DummyDedupe
dedupeFile fp dd = LB.readFile fp >>= return . (`dedupeBlocks` dd) . toBlocks 512

main :: IO ()
main = do
  dd <- getArgs >>= (`dedupeFile` empty) . head
  putStrLn . show . (*512) . size $ dd
  putStrLn . show . (*512) . foldl' (+) 0 $ dd
```

It works, but I got frustrated with its execution time and memory usage. Especilly when I compared with those of C++ and even Python implementation listed below, it was 3~5x slower and consumed 2~3x more memory space.

```
import os
import os.path
import sys

def dedupeFile(dd, fp):
    fd = os.open(fp, os.O_RDONLY)
    for block in iter(lambda : os.read(fd, 512), ''):
        dd.setdefault(block, 0)
        dd[block] = dd[block] + 1
    os.close(fd)
    return dd

dd = {}
dedupeFile(dd, sys.argv[1])

print(len(dd) * 512)
print(sum(dd.values()) * 512)
```

I thought it was mainly due to the hashmap implementation, and tried other implementations such as `hashmap`, `hashtables` and `unordered-containers`.
But there wasn't any noticeable difference.

Please help me to improve this program.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you will be able to beat the performance of python dictionaries. They are actually implemented in c with years of optimizations put into it on the other hand hashmap is new and not that much optimized. So getting 3x performance in my opinion is good enough. You can optimize you haskell code at certain places but still it won't matter much. If you are still adamant about increasing performance I think you should use a highly optimized c library with ffi in your code.

Here are some of the similar discussions

[haskell beginners](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.beginners/10033)

Comment: Actually, what I care most is memory usage, I can't understand the excessive memory usage of Haskell hashmaps. E.g. When the input file contained just 600MB unique data, it used up about 1GB memory or more. Anyway, thanks for your answer and article links. I should consider using FFI.

Comment: @comatose, that's just GHC.  GHC garbage collection strategy uses a copying collector, which is really fast, but has a 2x memory overhead.

Answer (score 3):

This may be completely irrelevant depending on your usage, but I am slightly worried about `insertWith (+) block 1`.  If your counts reach high numbers, you will accumulate thunks in the cells of the hash map.  It doesn't matter that you used `($!)`, that only forces the spine -- the values are likely still lazy.

`Data.HashMap` provides no strict version `insertWith'` like `Data.Map` does.  But you can implement it:

```
insertWith' :: (Hashable k, Ord k) => (a -> a -> a) -> k -> a 
                                   -> HashMap k a -> HashMap k a
insertWith' f k v m = maybe id seq maybeval m'
    where
    (maybeval, m') = insertLookupWithKey (const f) k v m
```

Also, you may want to output (but not input) a list of *strict* ByteStrings from `toBlocks`, which will make hashing faster.

That's all I've got -- I'm no performance guru, though.

Comment: I was able to squeeze a little out by creating a `data Blk = Blk {-# UNPACK #-} Word64 ... ` to hold the 512 bytes.  A sizable performance increase occurs if you switch to strict ByteStrings, but I'm not sure how much of that is due to effects such as cache and how much is due to my old nemesis of lazy ByteString chunks not having a sensible alignment (which worries me because it causes braches, copying, etc).  Ultimately, `unordered-containers` did the best (4.8 sec py vs 6.5 sec hs, but that was strict bytestrings) while `hashtable` was just frustrating due to no `insertWith` operation.

Comment: @luqui Thanks for your answer, i learnt something from you. Actually, there is `Data.HashMap.Strict` in `unordered-containers` and I tried that, but it couldn't make the situation better and the strict `ByteString` neither. `toStrict` is somewhat expensive.

Comment: `toStrict` might be a benefit if you change the `defaultChunkSize` to a multiple of `512` then recompile/install bytestring.  Without doing that the `toStrict` function is going to end up copying data at almost every chunk boundary.